# GCP suspension preventing access to our data

Tags: google-cloud-platform, standards-compliance

We have a Google Cloud Virtual Machine type N1 with 8 vCPU.
The VM is used for restoring DB and extensive manipulation of the data.

Google compliance team suspended the VM thinking we are involved in cryptocurrency mining.
This was done brutally, without warning. After we appealed - we had a long discussion and at the end they re-instated the VM.

Now it happened again - and we are not able to access our data.

Questions:

1. Did it happen to anyone else? What did you do?
2. If preventing access to our data is illegal - Did anyone try to act on the legal side?

Any help will be appreciated.
Tal

Comment: Consult [Google support](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub) for your issue.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that your Google Cloud Project is Blocked or Abuse is Detected from your Google Cloud Platform Compute Engine, you can check this [Policy violations FAQ](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7002354) for more details about the Google Cloud policy violation.

What you can do if your Google Cloud Platform is suspended is to contact the Cloud Billing Support team by following this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/support/billing#how_to_contact_support), they can help you to reinstate your access to your GCP projects.